# Read large file in chunks, compress and write in chunks

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling, zlib, deflate

I've come up against an issue due to large file sizes and processing them, the files are gradually increasing in size and will continue to do into the future. I can only use deflate as a compression option due to limitations on the 3rd party application I upload the compressed file to.

There is limited memory on the server running the script, so the usual issues with memory occur, hence why I'm trying to read in chunks and write in chunks with the output being the required deflated file.

Up to this point I've been using this snippet to compress the files to reduce the size and it's been working fine till now when the files are two big to process/compress.

```
with open(file_path_partial, 'rb') as file_upload, open(file_path, 'wb') as file_compressed:
    file_compressed.write(zlib.compress(file_upload.read()))
```

Some of the different options I've tried to get around it, all of which have failed to work properly so far.

1)

```
with open(file_path_partial, 'rb') as file_upload:
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as file_compressed:
        with gzip.GzipFile(file_path_partial, 'wb', fileobj=file_compressed) as file_compressed:
            shutil.copyfileobj(file_upload, file_compressed)
```

2)

```
BLOCK_SIZE = 64

compressor = zlib.compressobj(1)

filename = file_path_partial

with open(filename, 'rb') as input:
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as file_compressed:
        while True:            
            block = input.read(BLOCK_SIZE)
            if not block:
                break
            file_compressed.write(compressor.compress(block))
```

Comment: could you please post the error messages that show up for each of your attempts?

Comment: just to be 100% sure. you want to read in a huge file chunkwise and write it gzip compressed to another file?

Between reading and wroting you want to do some processing?

Comment: @gelonida, the error I get back from the 3rd party API is that it's an invalid deflated file in both of my examples above.

Comment: Did you try my answer? (obviously replace "test.txt" with your file name)

If yes, can you copy paste the exact error message?

If no error, does it do what you want?

Comment: The problem might be with this line `compressor = zlib.compressobj(1)`.   It will produce a zlib formatted stream by default.  And it appears you want gzip format?  Try changing the wbits parameter of compressobj() to 25.  Wbits is the 3rd argument (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html).  Second problem is block size of 64 is too small.  You should use a block of few KB at least to get good compression

Answer (score 2):

below example reads in 64k chunks, modifies each block and writes it out to a gzip file.

Is this what you want?

```
import gzip

with open("test.txt", "rb") as fin, gzip.GzipFile("modified.txt.gz", "w") as fout:
    while True:
        block = fin.read(65536) # read in 64k blocks
        if not block:
            break
        # comment next line to just write through
        block = block.replace(b"a", b"A")
        fout.write(block)
```